# Using Camunda engine with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, camunda

There is a need to organize electronic document management.Is it possible to use Camunda engine for business processes and statuses and Spring MVC as pages to use your own design ? Can not understand asked a question with Camunda did not work.

Comment: If you speak Russian, consider asking this question in the "Camunda BPM" group -- https://t.me/camunda_bpm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to use a workflow engine for business process state management, error handling, etc and implement pages, page flow within a task and UI state using Spring MVC.
Usually page flow has a finer granularity (following work description, different parts of same task such as different tabs) than workflow (finest level is reached when responsibilities can be assigned to systems and people).